# Multiple matching words in regex python

Tags: python

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y2TJ.jpg)
The requirement is to pull the exactly next word after the search word and write to the MODEL column.
To pull features, we have only one word ie. FEATURE and write the corresponding feature to its model.
Some models may not have features.

Models will be alphanumeric in nature and features can be single alphabet or an alphanumeric word.

Attaching Image of the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
STRING-1 = "YOU POSSESS PRODUCT CAR1 HAVING FEATURE O. PART CAR2 HAVING FEATURE Z. SPECIFICATION CAR3 HAVING FEATURE D."

STRING-2 = "YOU POSSESS PRODUCT CAR4 HAVING FEATURE O. PART CAR5 HAVING FEATURE Z."

STRING-3 = "YOU POSSESS PRODUCT CAR6."

search_words = [
"PRODUCT",
"PART",
"SPECIFICATION"
]

MODEL = []

for search_word in search_words:
    MODEL.append(STRING-1.split(search_word, 1)[1].split()[0])
    MODEL.append(STRING-2.split(search_word, 1)[1].split()[0])
    MODEL.append(STRING-3.split(search_word, 1)[1].split()[0])
print(MODEL)
```

Output:

```
['CAR1', 'CAR2', 'CAR3', 'CAR4', 'CAR5', 'CAR6']
```

Comment: As there will be multiple strings. It is giving error as IndexError: list index out of range.
Please suggest for the output as presented in desired output image.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> rx = re.compile( r"(?i)(?:PRODUCT|PART|SPECIFICATION)\s+(\w+)(?:\s+HAVING\s+FEATURE\s+(\w+))?" )
>>>
>>> input = '''
... Sample Input String-1: YOU POSSESS PRODUCT CAR1 HAVING FEATURE O. PART CAR2 HAVING FEATURE Z. SPECIFICATION CAR3 HAVING FEATURE D.
... Sample Input String-2: YOU POSSESS PRODUCT CAR4 HAVING FEATURE O. PART CAR5.
... Sample Input String-3: YOU POSSESS PRODUCT CAR6 HAVING FEATURE G.
... '''
>>>
>>> rx.findall(input)
[('CAR1', 'O'), ('CAR2', 'Z'), ('CAR3', 'D'), ('CAR4', 'O'), ('CAR5', ''), ('CAR6', 'G')]
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/xxnL13/1)

Comment: There is a situation where PART is followed by the word CONTROL and not by any model number like CAR2. If there is no alphnumeric word after the search word then we are not suppose to capture it. The output was ('CONTROL', '').  Another issue with output ('SPECIFICATION', ''). Instead of capturing the alphnumeric word, it captured the word itself. It is not capturing the features as well. Please suggest.

Comment: or could avoid known hazzards `(?i)(?:PRODUCT|PART(?!\s*CONTROL)|SPECIFICATION)\s+(\w+)(?:\s+HAVING\s+FEATURE\s+(\w+))?` but require `alpha` and `num`  might be tricky as well, make choice